# A word for indescribable pain; melancholic longing?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

"Have you ever experienced a brand-new feeling that welled up inside of your heart and filled you with indescribable pain?"

A quote from the English translation of *Cowboy Bebop: The Movie*. Two characters are discussing a sort of painful, melancholic longing, like love but perhaps a new feeling entirely.

The Portuguese word *saudade* seems close, but I am aware that it does not have an English counterpart.

Is there a word I haven't heard that fits this description?

Comment: You're looking for a word to *describe* something that is *indescribable*?

Comment: Most definitely! @AvnerShahar-Kashtan

Comment: Excruciating maybe?

Comment: @epizeuxis The translators may have gone with "indescribable" because there is literally no English word! On the other hand, they may be intentionally referring to the amount, rather than the type of pain -- "indescribable pain" meaning so painful that there isn't even a word to describe it (although "excruciating" would usually suffice). How would you describe what "saudade" means?

Comment: @nxx "'the love that remains' after someone is gone" "a deep emotional state of nostalgic or deeply melancholic longing for an absent something or someone that one loves" [saudade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade)

Comment: @epizeuxis How about heartsickness? heartsick = "despondent, typically from grief or loss of love." That's the most relevant definition I found (it is often defined without reference to loss of love). Note it appears when I search "heartsick" in Google, but it is not a link I can click on (Google dictionary??). Then there are related words like "despondency" = http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despondent. Am I getting close?

Comment: Most definitely excruciating ...... Not maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 'yearning' is what you're looking for, although I love 'saudade' myself. One of those words watered down by common misuse, but the definition of yearning is "1. deep longing, esp. when accompanied by tenderness or sadness."

Answer (score 2):

There are several adjectives often used for such emotional pain, including

> **[pining](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pining)** - *to feel great longing or desire; yearn* and *to mourn or grieve for*
>
> **[wrenching](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wrenching)** - *causing great physical or mental suffering* [also *gut-wrenching*]
>
> **[aching](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ache?q=ache)** - >*feel intense sadness or compassion*

Answer (score 1):

Two words come to my mind:

> **[insurmountable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insurmountable)** - *incapable of being surmounted, passed over, or overcome; insuperable.*
>
> **[overwhelming](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overwhelming)** - *overpowering; so great as to render resistance or opposition useless.*

Answer (score 0):

> **[torment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/torment)** - *Any extreme pain, anguish or misery, either physical or mental.*

And the author of that definition seems to have thrown in "anguish" and "misery" as a bonus.